# Magento 2 catalog search for SKU with dot not working

Tags: magento2, catalog, search, sku

our SKU's have dot's like: "120.00085"
If I search this string I get all products with "120.XXXX".
But the product with exact this SKU is not at the first position in the results.

Is there any solutions? I use Magento 2.2.4 version.

Best regards
Michael

Comment: That's not the default behavior, are you using any search extensions?

Comment: Thank you, you are right! I have tested it in a clean Magento installation and it works. In the current shop there are so much extensions installed...